# "Top of the morning to you" Is it formal or informal?

Tags: slang

Just like in title. Is the phrase "Top of the morning to you" formal or informal, but like would it be wrong if I said it to for example teacher?

Comment: If you are Irish I think you use it with anyone.

Comment: In British English it's more dated than anything else, in modern speech it would come across as a bit of a joke. It's not rude (well it could be in a cod-Irish accent).

Comment: In America I think the teacher would likely say to themselves, "What's up with him? He's way too chipper this morning."

Comment: Yes, it would be regarded as "cute" in the US.  Certainly it's OK if you wish to convey a sense of fun early in the morning.  But not the greeting you should likely give the president of a large corporation, upon being introduced.

Comment: @HotLicks It is the kind of thing that is only said with irony - unless you are Irish!

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51427/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-top-of-the-morning-to-you, at least as far as usage goes.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, this is stereotypically Irish. A non-Irish person saying it would appear very strange, unless they were clearly making a joke. (How much Irish people really say it, I don't know). Formality doesn't enter into it.

Comment: Well I live in Ireland and I have never heard any one say in real life; it is mainly  on TV comedy shows in a fake/'Oirish' context.

Answer (score 0):

Always thought it was an Irish expression because of how people spoke it here, but  what would I know. I’m Maori - native New Zealander!! Haha! We say it as a bit of a joke, like how we would imagine a leprachaun  would say it. Ok, I don’t need a lesson on leprachauns!!  But here in Kiwiland, we consider the use of the expression a cheery way to greet someone at the beginning of the day. (Not sure if moderators will accept my post, but that’s all good!)

Answer (score 0):

This phrase appears to come from the 1600s in England. There does seem to be some debate as to the possibility of it coming from the Irish language, however people from Gaeltacht areas(irish speaking villages) have told me that this is not true. It appears to have been associated with Ireland in America, and thus Irish americans started using it.

Comment: Do you have a source for _This phrase appears to come from the 1600s in England_?